# Can Cayley's Theorem be applied to groups with infinite order?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism

I've been reading Joseph Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* and I'm reading about isomorphisms. I came across Cayley's Theorem, which states:

> Every group is isomorphic to a group of permutations.

I asked my professor if this is true for groups with infinite order, like $\mathbb{Z}$, and he said that Cayley's Theorem only applies to groups with finite order. However, after looking at the proof of Cayley's Theorem in the book, it seems that it doesn't have to be constrained to finite groups. Is there anyway to be crafty and come up with such a group of permutations that is isomorphic to, say, $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition? If not, why?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_n$ has finite order $n$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster fixed!

Comment: Typically a permutation is a bijection from a *finite* set to itself. In that sense your professor was right, in fact any infinite group is a counterexample. But it generalizes to sets of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The group $\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to the group of all permutations of $\mathbb Z$ of the form $m\mapsto m+n$ ($n\in\mathbb Z$).

More generally, if $G$ is *any* group, then $G$ is isomorphic to the group of all permutations of $G$ of the form $g\mapsto gh$ ($h\in G$).

Comment: Since I just started learning about this, I can't help but view a permutation as a 'mapping' of a set of elements to itself (I tend to literally picture the arrows in my head). Is there an analogue of your answer to this way of thinking about a permutation?

Comment: @TyJensen A permutation is a bijection from a set to *the same* set. This is the definition used in the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Your professor is incorrect.  *Any* group $G$ acts on itself by left multiplication, and this action gives an embedding of $G$ in $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$.

Thus *every* group is isomorphic to a subgroup of a group of permutations.  And that is precisely what Cayley's theorem states.